# Cannot execute userform from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this userform code that cannot be execute from other sheet, so it can only be executed from sheet 6 (Activity Data). When i tried to execute it from other sheet, it shows

> runtime error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Click()
Dim t As Double
With ComboBox5
    t = Val(.List(.ListIndex))
    .value = Format(t, "hh:mm")
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox8_Click()
Dim t As Double
With ComboBox8
    t = Val(.List(.ListIndex))
    .value = Format(t, "hh:mm")
End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim activity_id As String
activity_id = ComboBox9.value
Lastrow = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 7).value = activity_id Then
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 8).value = ComboBox1.value
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 9).value = TextBox1.Text
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 11).value = ComboBox2.value
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 12).value = ComboBox3.value
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 13).value = ComboBox4.value
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 14).value = ComboBox5.value
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 15).value = ComboBox8.value
Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 10).value = TextBox2.Text
End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim activity_id As String
activity_id = ComboBox9.value
Lastrow = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 7).value = activity_id Then
ComboBox1.value = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 8).value
TextBox1.Text = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 9).value
ComboBox2.value = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 11).value
ComboBox3.value = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 12).value
ComboBox4.value = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 13).value
ComboBox5.value = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 14).value
ComboBox8.value = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 15).value
TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Activity Data").Cells(i, 10).value
End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 ComboBox9.RowSource = Sheets("Activity Data").Range("G2", Range("G65536").End(xlUp)).Address
 End Sub
```

Comment: Depending on the name of the user form, try something like 'Userform1.CommandButton4_Click'.

Comment: Maybe this line `ComboBox9.RowSource = Sheets("Activity Data").Range("G2", Range("G65536").End(xlUp)).Address` should be like this `ComboBox9.RowSource = Sheets("Activity Data").Range("G2", Sheets("Activity Data").Range("G65536").End(xlUp)).Address`

Comment: It makes the userform executable from different sheet but makes the rowsource become unavailable. Any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *I have this userform code that cannot be **execute** from other sheet*. When does the error occur? What do you do or click to cause the error?

Comment: I tried to click the command button that suppose to show the userform but it shows error

Comment: What is the code behind the `Commandbutton`? do you have a button on each sheet with identical code, or are there different things happening also?

Comment: I use code userform2.show on the commandbutton. Another userform works fine